# How to turn the richeditcontrol devexpress Delphi 11 page with a code

Tags: devexpress, rad-studio, richedit-control

There is a richeditcontrol component in the devexpress component set. This object adds a standard page, like wordpad. I need to turn this page into landscape orientation using the code.
I use rad studio delphi 11.

I tried to do this:

`dxRichEditControl1.Document.Sections[0].Page.Landscape := true;`

but the page did not turn over.

I accidentally came across "`dockorientation`", but I can't figure out how to use it, and where to insert it.

I also tried to do this:

```
var
 orientation: TDockOrientation;

begin

  orientation := doHorizontal;
  dxRichEditControl1.DockOrientation := orientation;
```

Comment: Docking has nothing to do with page orientation. Also, have you asked this question at DevEx support?

Comment: I am not allowed on the devexpress forum :(

Comment: Why not? They offer free support to their registered users via their forums.

Comment: O! I managed to log in. the email came with a confirmation

Answer (score 0):

I did it! I used "landscape" in the "form.create" block, but I should have used "form.show".

```
procedure TFReports.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  dxRichEditControl1.Document.Sections[0].Page.Landscape := true;
end;
```